# Arrange corresponding text

Tags: html, css

On the right side of the website you will find 2 images and text next to the image

This is the HTML code for what I said:

```
<div id="contact-info">
    <div id="adresa">
        <div id="addPadding" style="padding: 2em;">
            <img src="http://avocat.dac-proiect.ro/wp/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/images/ADRESA.png" style="width:22px;height:31px;float:left;display: inline;">
            <div style="float: right;display: inline;width: 80%;">
                <p style="text-align:left;">Calea Dorobantilor,nr.74,<br>bl.Y9,SC.2,Ap.25<br>Cluj-Napoca,400609<br>Romania</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="telefon">
        <div id="addPadding" style="padding-top: 90px;">
            <img src="http://avocat.dac-proiect.ro/wp/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/images/TELEFON.png" style="width:22px;height:31px;float:left;display: inline;">
            <div style="float: right;display: inline;width: 80%;">
                <p style="text-align:left;">Calea Dorobantilor,nr.74,<br>bl.Y9,SC.2,Ap.25<br>Cluj-Napoca,400609<br>Romania</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  

    <div id="mail"></div>
</div></div>
```

I want to move text and images in the second row to be like in the first line

This is the site:

http://avocat.dac-proiect.ro/wp/

I tried to add padding-left at this code `<div id="addPadding" style="padding-top: 90px;padding-left:X value;">` but arrange it properly

How can I solve this problem?

Thank You!

Comment: So you are trying to make it so the telephone and location info are on the same line so it would go image-text-image-text all on one line?

Comment: Use unique IDs in your html, `id="addPadding"` is used twice.

Comment: You should definitely use a table. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
style="padding-top: 90px;
```

to this:

```
style="padding: 90px 2em;
```

(And change the `id` of the second div so that it is unique.)

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ta1msgak/)

Answer (score 0):

Put everything in a table like this

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://avocat.dac-proiect.ro/wp/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/images/ADRESA.png">
        </td>
        <td>
            <p style="text-align:left;">Calea Dorobantilor,nr.74,<br>bl.Y9,SC.2,Ap.25<br>Cluj-Napoca,400609<br>Romania</p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="http://avocat.dac-proiect.ro/wp/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/images/TELEFON.png">
        </td>
        <td>
            <p style="text-align:left;">Calea Dorobantilor,nr.74,<br>bl.Y9,SC.2,Ap.25<br>Cluj-Napoca,400609<br>Romania</p>
        </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

tr is a row tag and td is a column tag. I wouldn't do this with CSS it is much harder.